# Bash script ghost txt files

Tags: bash, sed, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, zenity

I have written a script, that prompts the user for some input, takes that input and changes a txt file according to these choices.

```
#!/bin/bash

#info für dpi vom user abfragen und als variable speichern
var_dpi=$(zenity --list --radiolist --text "Please select <b>DPI</b> setting" --hide-header --column "Select" --column "DPI" FALSE "4800" FALSE "2400" FALSE "1200" FALSE "600" FALSE "300" FALSE "150" FALSE "100" FALSE "75")

#echo "$var_dpi"

#warnung wenn DPI über 1200

if [ "$var_dpi" -gt 1200 ]; then
   #zenity --warning --text "Bei dieser Auflösung übersteigt die Dateigröße 1GB" --width=200 --height=100
   zenity --question --text "Bei dieser Auflösung übersteigt die Dateigröße 1GB. Sind Sie sicher das Sie "$var_dpi" DPI übernehmen möchten?" --width=400 --height=100
   #echo "$var_answer"


   if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    var_dpi=$(zenity --list --radiolist --text "Please select <b>DPI</b> setting" --hide-header --column "Select" --column "DPI" FALSE "4800" FALSE "2400" FALSE "1200" FALSE "600" FALSE "300" FALSE "150" FALSE "100" FALSE "75")
   fi

fi


#variable nehmen und im script ersetzen
sed -i "s/4800/$var_dpi/g;s/2400/$var_dpi/g;s/1200/$var_dpi/g;s/600/$var_dpi/g;s/300/$var_dpi/g;s/150/$var_dpi/g;s/100/$var_dpi/g;s/75/$var_dpi/g" /home/pi/Documents/text_test

#info für colour/no colour abfragen
var_color=$(zenity --list --radiolist --text "Please select <b>Colour or Grey</b> setting" --hide-header --column "Select" --column "Colour Setting" FALSE "colour" FALSE "gray")

#echo "$var_color"

#colour ersetzen
sed -i "s/color/$var_color/g;s/gray/$var_color/g" /home/pi/Documents/text_test

#info für format abfragen
var_format=$(zenity --list --radiolist --text "Please select <b>Format</b> setting" --hide-header --column "Select" --column "Format" FALSE "tiff" FALSE "jpg")

#echo "$var_format"

#format ersetzen
sed -i "s/tiff/$var_format/g;s/jpg/$var_format/g" /home/pi/Documents/text_test
```

I am pretty sure it is very crude, but it works.

The only problem is, when i run it, sometimes txt files are created in the same directory the script and the file it alters are located(/home/pi/Documents).

These txt files are empty when i open them. The first one is 128kb in size, the next one 129kb an so on. After a reboot they are gone.

Does anyone have a idea what is going on or is it ok to just ignore it?

Comment: What are the names of the ghost files?

Comment: e.g.
sedqNrh1g , 
sedqsJOdd

Comment: I'm guessing since they start with `sed` that they're temp files your `sed -i` is using for its pseudo "in place" editing. Check the man page of the sed version you're running to see if it actually requires a file name after the `-i`. Also try just not using "inplace" editing and instead use a tmp file that you have control over yourself, e.g. instead of `sed -i 'script' file` do `tmp=$(mktemp); sed 'script' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file`.

Comment: FYI `sed -i "s/4800/$var_dpi/g;s/2400/$var_dpi/g;s/1200/$var_dpi/g;s/600/$var_dpi/g;s/300/$var_dpi/g;s/150/$var_dpi/g;s/100/$var_dpi/g;s/75/$var_dpi/g"` can be written more concisely as `sed -E -i 's/4800|2400|1200|600|300|150|100|75/'"$var_dpi"'/g'` (I corrected your quotes too). Ditto for `sed -Ei 's/color|gray/'"$var_color"'/g'`